# why ObjectDataSource not sending correct parameter value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ObjectDataSource in which I was trying to pass some parameters.

```
GridDataSource.SelectMethod = "GetAllCountries";
GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("PageSize", pageSize.ToString());
GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("OrderBy", orderBy);
GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("StartIndex", startIndex.ToString());
```

and my method is in App_Code/DAL/CountriesDB.CS

```
public  List<Countries> GetAllCountries(int PageSize,string OrderBy,int StartIndex)
{
..........
}
```

when I debugged it, in GetAllCountries Method PageSize=-1;OrderBy="",StartIndex=0 is passed...what is going on here??

thnx in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Handle the `Selecting` event of `GridDataSource` and enter your parameters there.

```
protected void GridDataSource_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{    
    GridDataSource.SelectMethod = "GetAllCountries";            
    e.InputParameters.Clear();
    e.InputParameters.Add("PageSize", pageSize.ToString());
    e.InputParameters.Add("OrderBy", orderBy);
    e.InputParameters.Add("StartIndex", startIndex.ToString());         
}
```

Comment: I m getting this error:

The Select operation is not supported by ObjectDataSource 'GridDataSource' unless the SelectMethod is specified.

Comment: See if this post helps http://www.eranachum.com/PermaLink,guid,089badbf-c01c-4363-a236-617ccf85ce3b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try that way :

```
GridDataSource.SelectMethod = "GetAllCountries";
 Parameter p1 = new Parameter("PageSize",TypeCode.Int32);
 Parameter p2 = new Parameter("OrderBy",TypeCode.String);
 Parameter p3 = new Parameter("StartIndex",TypeCode.Int32);
 GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(p1);
 GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(p2);
 GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(p3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually subscribe to the [`ObjectDataSource`'s `Selecting` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selecting.aspx), where I can modify the `InputParmeters` collection in [ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs `e`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasourcemethodeventargs.aspx):

```
e.InputParameters["PageSize"] = pageSize; // pageSize is an int in your select method
e.InputParameters["OrderBy"] = orderBy;
e.InputParameters["StartIndex"] = startIndex; // startindex is an int too
```

Besides, the parameter values do not need to be strings. They should match the select method's parameters' types.

The select method must be specified either in code (just as you did in your question):

```
GridDataSource.SelectMethod = "GetAllCountries"; // code
```

... or in the markup:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ... SelectMethod="GetAllCountries" /> // markup
```

Comment: Getting an error:

The Select operation is not supported by ObjectDataSource 'GridDataSource' unless the SelectMethod is specified.

Comment: @TamalKantiDey You need so specify it. Edited my post.

Comment: It'd help if you'd update the question with an up-to-date short-but-complete version (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) of what you tried. Especially the event handlers should be visible.